# How can I force SBT to download and use a later version of itself?

Tags: sbt, fedora-25

I am using SBT on Fedora 25, which comes with version 0.13.1.  This is an old version, and [has bugs](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2923) that prevent it from working with Java 8.

Is there a way to tell SBT to download a new copy of itself, then use the new copy?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `build.properties` in the `project` directory in your sbt project's root with the version you want set:

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```

See [the relevant page in the manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html#Specifying+the+sbt+version) for more info.